# Enabling opcache.restrict_api for security reasons

Tags: php-fpm, php7

[This article](https://ma.ttias.be/mitigating-phps-long-standing-issue-opcache-leaking-sensitive-data/) says that having [`opcache_get_status()`](http://php.net/opcache_get_status) enabled is a security risk. To turn it off, one has to configure `opcache.restrict_api`, but I couldn't find an example of how.

[This person](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2834#issuecomment-402465194) had the restriction in effect when configured as `opcache.restrict_api=/restricted`, which gives me a clue that it needs to be a path.

I started by creating a test script with an `opcache_get_status()` call, and I got an output of lots of PHP scripts on that system, confirming there was no restriction. Then I edited my `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini` to have `opcache.restrict_api=/dev/null`, and that same call now returns `bool(false)` - I take that the restriction is enabled.

My goal is to forbid `opcache_get_status()` and the like completely, and by 'allowing' scripts under `/dev/null`, I'm essentially making it impossible to use, since you can't a file there.

- Is this logic correct?
- Should I maybe use some other path?
- Is there a way to enable the restriction directly, without messing around with fake paths?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code of [ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/345703724c633fb8c1b34e1299bf3375f000c398/ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.c)

- For the information to 'leak', [`validate_api_restriction()` needs to return `true`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/345703724c633fb8c1b34e1299bf3375f000c398/ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.c#L591).
- In [that function itself](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/345703724c633fb8c1b34e1299bf3375f000c398/ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.c#L71), it takes `SG(request_info).path_translated` (which, apparently, [equals to `SCRIPT_FILENAME`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c#L909)) and [matches it against `restrict_api`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/345703724c633fb8c1b34e1299bf3375f000c398/ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.c#L78), comparing [first few characters](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcmp.htm) of the two values.
- Since the first character of `path_translated` a.k.a. `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is a slash, `opcache.restrict_api=1` won't match it (`/` != `1`), and looks therefore safe to use

Also [here's someone else using `opcache.restrict_api=1`](https://discourse.getgrav.org/t/again-zend-opcache-api-is-restricted-by-restrict-api-configuration-directive/4569/9) too.

Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere! Until then, I feel like this pretty much answers my question.